# Obter conexão com banco de dados em HTML e JS

Tags: javascript, soap, jquery-mobile

Como obter a conexão com o banco de dados via SOAP usando HTML e JavaScript?
Utilizo o Jquery Mobile.
Estou Fazendo um sistema de login, e necessito transportar as informações dos inputs para o adapter do Worklight para assim se conectar ao banco de dados e retornar as mensagens de sucess ou fail e, caso seja sucess, avançar a tela do login.

Comment: Você necessariamente precisa de uma linguagem *server side* como PHP, Ruby, Python, outras... Só com HTML e Javascript é impossível!

Comment: Não é uma pergunta ampla, pelo contrário, é uma pergunta extremamente limitada.

Comment: está bem limitado o que quero.. Peço que reavaliem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não deveria utilizar JavaScript para acessar banco de dados por diversas razões, mas se vocẽ realmente quiser fazer isso, segue um exemplo:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Uma boa forma de fazer isso seria usando linguagens secundárias, como PHP, Java, .NET entre outras.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou sim! Muito obrigado @jpklzm

Comment: Apesar de funcionar, e ajudar, como o @jpklzm mesmo diz "Você não deveria utilizar JavaScript para acessar banco de dados por diversas razões", eu recomendo que você busque outra solução mais apropriada, pois utilizar conexão com o banco de dados no javascript deixa sua aplicação totalmente sem segurança. No javascript eu recomendaria utilizar o ajax para comunicar com alguma linguagem no servidor (java, php, c#), e la sim você faz sua aplicação se comunicar com a base de dados.

Comment: Obrigado @EricoSouza!!

Answer (score 0):

Não, não é possível considere usar webservices e efetuar a comunicação com o ajax do jquery.

Comment: Olá @Hiago, você tem algum artigo em que eu possa estar aprendendo sobre isso?

Comment: Teria que 1º aprender a construir um serviço SOAP, não sei se conhece o php mais acho que vai ser fácil para vc aprender, com isso pronto estude como consumir webservice SOAP em PHP com jquery ajax.

Porque tem diversas maneiras, não é um tutorial e sim vários que vc terá que pesquisar, mais é isso.

1º - Criando serviço SOAP em php.
2º - Consumindo serviço SOAP em php com jquery ajax.

E o resto é lógica e imaginação cara.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Comment: A pergunta do Renan foi: "é possível ?" Resposta: "Não" ! Em momento algum critiquei apenas dei uma sugestão, porém acredito que a pergunta foi respondida caso não tenha sido, coloque uma resposta correta.

Comment: Hiago, eu concordo com você, isso responde a pergunta. Porém, quanto mais detalhada a resposta, melhor. Esse comentário do @BrunoAugusto veio pelo [sistema de análise do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review), e a sua resposta foi parar lá automaticamente por ser muito curta (portanto, o sistema suspeitou que ficaria melhor como comentário, pelo comprimento).

Comment: Tudo bem, apenas quis dizer que em momento algum minha resposta está incorreta, peço desculpas pois sempre me ajudam aqui e só queria retribuir de alguma forma, só não sabia como detalhar mais.

Comment: Sim, não precisa se desculpar. Eu só quis te dar uma dica de como funciona o sistema. Toda vez que você postar uma resposta, tente incluir mais detalhes explicando o problema. Senão a resposta vai parar automaticamente no sistema de revisão por pares, e pode acabar excluída pelos outros usuários. A sua resposta está no limite entre uma resposta e um comentário.

Comment: Entendi obrigado, e desculpa @BrunoAugusto se pareci grosso.

Comment: Uma boa alternativa ao SOAP, e acredito que mais simples, é utilizar REST (ou webapi). Principalmente para quem vai iniciar em webservices. Aqui tenho algumas referencias:
http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/07/asp-net-web-api-meu-primeiro-servico-rest/

http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível tratar a comunicação sem a utilização de um [Web Service](http://www.w3schools.com/Webservices/default.asp).
Notei em sua última pergunta (a qual excluiu), que você está tentando trabalhar com `Worklight`, portanto, sugiro a [essa leitura](http://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/criando-aplicativos-mobile-com-o-worklight/)

Comment: Oi Rafael, obrigado por participar, mas eu preciso de verdade me conectar com um banco de dados não-local.. Já vi este artigo quando eu ainda trabalhava na própria IBM!
Quanto ao Webservices, me aconselha alguma leitura que possa me ajudar? Obrigado!